# Help Translating 私の口には合わなかった

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

I'm translating a Q&A session for some friends (link [here](https://www.mitsudomoe-anime.com/mitsugonikike/an03.html)), and I'm having a bit of trouble with this question:

> Q: みっちゃんは地デジ対応ですか？
>
> A: ち、地デジ……？　ふ、ふふん、残念ながら、私の口には合わなかったわね！

I translated these as the following:

> Q: Do you have digital broadcasting at home, Micchan?
>
> A: D-digital broadcasting..? Heh, heheh... I'm sorry to say that it just isn't for me!

I took 対応 as "dealing with" (or having), and 合わなかった as "something I didn't agree with".

I have no idea what 私の口 means in this sentence, which makes me feel like I'm missing something crucial in this conversation.

How should these be translated?

Comment: Hi, can you give us the Q&A immediately prior to these? It seems to me that みっちゃん did not understand what 地デジ meant and probably thought it was some sort of food. It looks like she was just pretending to know what it was to not get embarrassed maybe. 口に合う or 合わない basically means to like or dislike the taste of food or drink.

Comment: Hmm, that does sound plausible. みっちゃん *is* a character that just loves to eat. Added the Q&A link in the question.

Comment: @DXV Thank you  for your time as well. Can you also tell me if I'm using the right meanings for the other words, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that みっちゃん did not understand what 地デジ meant and probably thought it was some sort of food. In her response it looks like she was just pretending to know what it was, maybe to avoid embarrassment. 口に合う or 合わない basically means to like or dislike the taste of food or drink.

As for 対応, みっちゃん is being asked if she (her tv, house, etc) can handle 地デジ, so I think that your translation is good.

p.s. How about Mitchan? I think it's a closer approximation to the sound of みっちゃん.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! As for Micchan/Mitchan, I was simply going with how the fanbase decided to translate her name. It's been in use for years, so I'm afraid I can't change it now.